Nativewind did'nt take effect on Image and ImageBackground component
I am working on a react native expo project, I used Nativewind for styling, while it works on text and view, it didn't work with Image or ImageBackground component. Has anyone experience this?
I am installing Nativewind based on this documentation.
https://www.nativewind.dev/getting-started/expo-router
